# Apache Ignite cache persist on local file system

Tags: ignite

Is it possible to persist the ignite cache on local file system?

I need to perform cache operations like insert, update, delete on my look up data.
But this has to be persisted on local file system of the respective nodes to survive the data even after restart of the ignite cluster.

Alternatively I was able to persist the data on MySQL database.

But I'm looking for a persistence solution that works independent of databases and HDFS.

Answer (score 2):

Ignite since version 2.1 has it own native Persistence. Moreover, it has advantages over integration with 3rd party databases.

You can read about it here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store